# ¿Cómo controlar visualizador PDF en vista móvil de sitio web sin descargarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, web, pdf

Buen día, tengo un problema con mi visualizador pdf, quiero que mi documento se visualice dentro de la pagina sin tener que descargarlo, en el ordenador funciona perfectamente pero al momento de abrir el pdf en el navegador del celular me pide que descargue el pdf, existe alguna manera para evitar la descarga y que solo se visualice?

este es el pedazo de estructura que tengo para mi visualizador

```
<div id="pdf">
    <object class="pdf" type="application/pdf" data="../../Catalogos/strokmatic/strokmatic_hidraulica.pdf" ></object>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. No es necesario QUE GRITES. :) Y pues, depende del navegador móvil que estés probando.